# cannot display icon from google places

Tags: java, android, google-places-api

I have been wrestling with this all night . Here's the issue I am using the google places api in my android project and want to use the icons provided in the json output. I have looked at the questions already posed and they all refer to javascript. Essentially in the log file it keeps stating that it can't find the file when I attempt to access this path. I can put the uri in the browse and it show up any ideas?
the uri is  http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png and heres the code it gives a warning too and when the marker is added (because its null errors out)

```
private Bitmap getBitmapFromUri(Uri uri) throws IOException {
AssetFileDescriptor FDescriptor =
        //getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = FDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor);
FDescriptor.close();
return image;
```

}

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the documentation for [openAssetFileDescriptor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#openAssetFileDescriptor%28android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String%29).  It doesn't handle the `http` scheme.  You will probably either want to download this file manually and then use a method like the above to load a local file or use a library like [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso), which will download and cache the image for you (and even load it into your ImageView).